# Improving an existing badge system for a Django web forum

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a Django forum where users post comments and interact with one another. Everyone has a nickname, and can write 250 characters per comment. There's also an upvote/downvote functionality to regulate the quality of comments.

Moreover, some *verified *users get badges. There's just one type of badge currently, and is given out to users with a certain real-life skill (we verify that via a background check).

Each badge shows up as nothing but a * next to a verified person's nickname. E.g.:

> mhb11: Have you checked out the reviews to the upcoming Civil War
>   movie? Here: [link]
>
> Swindon-411*: I bet BvS > MCW :-D
>
> samantha1: oh boy!

**Swindon-411*** above is one of those verified users. I list all verified nicknames in **nicknames.py**, and then export the list to **views.py**. Then in every Django template of the project, I do:

```
{% for person in verified %}
      {% if person == comment.submitter.username %}
            <span style="color:orange;"><b>*</b></span>
      {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Most of my templates contain this logic (which templates aren't supposed to). The project was small, so this approached worked prototypically. Now our users have scaled, and we're adding more badges too. I want to refactor the way I've implemented this.

What's the least performance intensive, scalable way to accomplish this in my Django web app? Should I have a middleware, that reads every request and concatenates a badge next to a nickname? Should I move it as a property to the DB? Each `User` in my app is from `django.contrib.auth.models`.

The best answer for me is one which outlines how you would do it, alongwith an illustrative example. I'm using Django < 1.8, and my backend is PostgreSQL. Thanks in advance. This project has taught me much, and learning continues here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO you should definitely move it in your DB. Manually maintained lists might seem a good idea now but are not scalable and will inevitably cause headaches later on.

The easiest approach is to create a `UserProfile` model ([see docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)) that can be used to store this and any other user information:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Profile(models.Model):
    # Tie this profile to a specific user.
    # You may need to set null=True if migrating a bunch of existing users
    # who don't have a profile.
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Then you can access this from anywhere using the standard reverse relationships:

```
  {% if person.profile.verified %}
       <span style="color:orange;"><b>*</b></span>
  {% endif %}
```

You should also make sure you add the appropriate `select_related` calls to your querysets so that the users and profile are fetched in the same DB query.

Comment: Wouldn't the template code get messy if we introduce multiple badges (like we intend to)?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You can always move some of the rendering logic into a template tag (e.g., `render_badge`) to remove duplication. I thought your question was about the best way to store the information.

Comment: Well store and rendering both. Thanks for the tip.